# TypeError: Instance of JSArray<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm trying to serialize/deserialize a list of JSON but i'm facing this error because dart is getting a js.Proxy type instead of list dynamic that i'm trying to achieve.

I have two classes: the main one and another one that is nested inside the first one.

Here's my code.

I appreciate every response.

```
import 'dart:convert';
main() {
 
  String horarios = '{"horarios": [{"id": "1", "horaInicio": "12", "horaFim": "14", "presenca": "1", "folga": "1"}, {"id": "1", "horaInicio": "12", "horaFim": "14", "presenca": "1", "folga": "2"}]}';
  print(horarios);
  return HorarioSingle.fromJson(jsonDecode(horarios)["horarios"]);  
}

class HorarioLinha {
  final String dia;
  final String horaInicio;
  final String horaFim;
  final String presenca;
  final String folga;

  HorarioLinha(
      {required this.dia,
      required this.horaInicio,
      required this.horaFim,
      required this.presenca,
      required this.folga});
  
  factory HorarioLinha.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HorarioLinha (
    dia: json['id'],
    horaInicio: json['horaInicio'],
    horaFim: json['horaFim'],
    presenca: json['presenca'],
    folga: json['folga'],
    
  );
}

class HorarioSingle{
  final List<HorarioLinha> horarios;
  
  HorarioSingle({required this.horarios});
 
  
  factory HorarioSingle.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HorarioSingle(
    horarios: List<HorarioLinha>.from(json['horarios'].map((horario) => HorarioLinha.fromJson(horario)))
  );
}
```

Is expected to be returned a list of my custom object

Comment: I bet it's because your conversion "jsonDecode(horarios)["horarios"]" remove all the ", then it's not a map anymore but an array.
You should either ensure that's your data are correctly set and can be decode to Map<String, dynamic> or change the parameter type of your fromJson methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  String horarios =
      '{"horarios": [{"id": "1", "horaInicio": "12", "horaFim": "14", "presenca": "1", "folga": "1"}, {"id": "1", "horaInicio": "12", "horaFim": "14", "presenca": "1", "folga": "2"}]}';
  print(horarios);
  return HorarioSingle.fromJson(jsonDecode(horarios));
}

class HorarioLinha {
  final String dia;
  final String horaInicio;
  final String horaFim;
  final String presenca;
  final String folga;

  HorarioLinha({required this.dia, required this.horaInicio, required this.horaFim, required this.presenca, required this.folga});

  factory HorarioLinha.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HorarioLinha(
        dia: json['id'],
        horaInicio: json['horaInicio'],
        horaFim: json['horaFim'],
        presenca: json['presenca'],
        folga: json['folga'],
      );

  static List<HorarioLinha> fromList(List<dynamic> jsonList) {
    final list = <HorarioLinha>[];
    for (final elementJson in jsonList) {
      try {
        final obj = HorarioLinha.fromJson(elementJson as Map<String, dynamic>);
        list.add(obj);
      } catch (e) {
        print('error $e parsing $elementJson');
      }
    }
    return list;
  }
}

class HorarioSingle {
  final List<HorarioLinha> horarios;

  HorarioSingle({required this.horarios});

  factory HorarioSingle.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HorarioSingle(horarios: HorarioLinha.fromList(json['horarios']));
}
```

Comment: You're right, is really what a wanted, saved me. Thanks so much

Comment: Glad I could help. My "fromList" method will result in invalid items being omitted from the list.  Alternatively, if you'd prefer an exception gets thrown, you could remove the try/catch

Comment: don't worry,  my API will never return elements that do not fit with my model